# Criterion for $\sigma$-additive measure on a semiring of sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $S$ be a semiring and $m$ be a measure on $S$. Show that $m$ is $\sigma$-additive on $S$ if and only if for any $A, \{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $S$ such that $A\subset \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ it follows that $m(A)\leq \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}m(A_n)$.

*Hint:* Let $S$ be a semiring and $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ in $S$ . Then there are pairwise disjoint sets $B_1,\dots,B_k$ in $S$ such that each $A_i$ is union of some $B_j$'s.

**My approach:** The direction $\Leftarrow$ is quite easy.

I have trouble with the direction $\Rightarrow$. It's not so difficult to show that if we have finite union, i.e. $A\subset \cup_{n=1}^{N} A_n$ then using this hint we can get $m(A)\leq \sum \limits_{n=1}^{N}m(A_n)$.

But I don't know how to apply this hint when we have countable union.

So I would be very grateful if you can show how to solve this problem, please!

Answer (score 1):

First construct a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets $\{D_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset S$ with the property that, for each $k \ge 1$, there is a set $\Lambda_k = \{i_1,\ldots,i_{n_k}\}$ such that

$$C_k = A_k \setminus (A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_{k-1}) = D_{i_1}\cup\ldots\cup D_{i_{n_k}}$$

(where $A_0 = \emptyset$). This is done inductively: Let $D_1 = A_1$, and assume the construction has been done for $1 \le i \le k$. Let $E_j = (A_{k+1} \setminus A_j),\ j = 1,\ldots,k$. By definition of semiring, there are pairwise disjoint sets $\{F_r\}$ in $S$ such that $E_j = \cup F_r$. Since $S$ is closed under intersections, it follows that $\cap E_j = C_{k+1}$ is also a union of pairwise disjoint sets of $S$. Adding these sets to the already constructed $D_i$'s extends that collection to one that satisfies the condition for $k+1$. Notice that the $C_k$'s are all disjoint, so the $\Lambda_k$'s are also disjoint.

Now, to prove the main fact, we may assume (by considering $A\cap A_n$ instead) that $A = \cup A_n$. From the construction above, it follows that

$$m(A) = m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right) = m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\right) $$
$$=
 m\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{i\in \Lambda_k} D_i\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i\in \Lambda_k} m(D_i)$$ $$ \le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} m(A_k) $$

Where the second line follows from the $\sigma$-additivity of $m$ and the last line follows from the fact that each $A_k$ is a union of some of the $D_i$'s so the sum on the right contains all the terms in the sum on the left and possibly more since the $A_k$'s are not assumed to be pairwise disjoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply but let me ask you a question: You wrote $m(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)$ but this union may not be an element of $S$ and this expression does not make sense.

Comment: @ZFR Oh my...that was silly of me. If the union belongs to $S$ the result is completely trivial, sorry about that. I rewrote the whole thing, hopefully I was more careful this time.